# Cannot connect to a gitlab-ci service from a job (sometimes)

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a job with some service

```
http1:
  services:
    - name: $MY_DOCKER_REGISTRY/simple-http:1.0.0
      alias: simple1
  script:
    - ping -c2 simple1
    - curl -sSL 'http://simple1:23232/files/sample.txt?token=deadbeef'
```

It works fine on the first of my runners and it doesn't work on the second.

In the failed case, after the pinging step I can see the `simple1` name was resolved as `172.17.0.5` while the real container has an IP `172.17.0.3` (I can see it from `docker network inspect ID`, also I can use that valid IP instead of name `simple1` - it works).

Runner configurations are identical. I have another job with other service (it was set up long time ago) that works fine on the both runners! Very strange...

Why there is the problem with resolving a service name?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It were 2 problems: a) one of the DNS servers returned a wrong IP for 'simple1'; b) there was defined a ALL_PROXY env variable, it interfered with work HTTP